# Does the conjunction "or" mean "that is to say"?

Tags: conjunctions

In *New Concept English*, there's such a sentence as:

> In this case, you'd probably construct a portfolio with some shares (but not high risk ones), along with gilts, cash deposits, and perhaps convertibles or the income shares of split capital investment trusts.

Is "the income shares of split capital investment trusts" the explanation of "convertibles"?

Comment: I edited the formatting of this question, but it looks as though you may have changed "or" to "and". Please edit to "or" if that's what the original sentence actually said.

Comment: My question is whether "or" means "that is to say" or not.

Comment: Then please edit your question to indicate that. Right now the second-to-last sentence says "convertibles **and** the income shares of split capital investment trusts".

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not. In this context, the “or” contrasts “convertibles” with “income shares…” This meaning can be deduced by the use of the word “perhaps” immediately preceding “convertibles,” which suggests a certain possibility or several possibilities. Here, these possibilities are simply separated by “or.”

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Annabeth Yeung,